# How to join 2 tables when second table will return more rows?

Tags: t-sql, join

im trying to join 2 tables with condition - if it matches than im expecting to get all results from another table.

Current querry that doesn't work :

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN ZL.NumerCzesci LIKE '%ZŁOŻENIE%' 
  THEN (SELECT NumerCzesci FROM PodZlozenie WHERE NumerPodZlozenia = ZL.NumerCzesci) ELSE ZL.NumerCzesci END) AS [NumerCzesci] FROM Zlozenie ZL LEFT JOIN PodZlozenie PD ON ZL.NumerZlozenia = PD.NumerPodZlozenia
```

Table [Zlozenie] looks like :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Zlozenie] (
    [Id_Zlozenia]   INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [NumerZlozenia] VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [NumerCzesci]   VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id_Zlozenia] ASC)
);
INSERT INTO Zlozenie (NumerZlozenia, NumerCzesci) VALUES ('300-001-000-ROTOR-3-1-3','300-000-001 - WKŁADKA GÓRNA');
INSERT INTO Zlozenie (NumerZlozenia, NumerCzesci) VALUES ('300-001-000-ROTOR-3-1-3','300-000-002 - WKŁADKA DOLNA');    
INSERT INTO Zlozenie (NumerZlozenia, NumerCzesci) VALUES ('300-001-000-ROTOR-3-1-3','300-000-003 - UCHO ROTORA 11 RAM 3 SEKCJE');    
INSERT INTO Zlozenie (NumerZlozenia, NumerCzesci) VALUES ('300-001-000-ROTOR-3-1-3','300-000-005 - RAMIĘ ROTORA 565mm');    
INSERT INTO Zlozenie (NumerZlozenia, NumerCzesci) VALUES ('300-021-000 - DACH-BA3-1','300-021-001 - ZŁOŻENIE POKRYWY GÓRNEJ BA3-1');
INSERT INTO Zlozenie (NumerZlozenia, NumerCzesci) VALUES ('300-021-000 - DACH-BA3-1','300-021-002 - ZŁOŻENIE POKRYWY DOLNEJ TYŁ BA3-1');
INSERT INTO Zlozenie (NumerZlozenia, NumerCzesci) VALUES ('300-021-000 - DACH-BA3-1','300-021-003 - ZŁOŻENIE POKRYWY DOLNEJ PRZÓD BA3-1');
```

Table [PodZlozenie] looks like :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PodZlozenie] (
    [Id_PD]            INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [NumerPodZlozenia] VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [NumerCzesci]      VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO PodZlozenie (NumerPodZlozenia, NumerCzesci) VALUES ('300-021-001 - ZŁOŻENIE POKRYWY GÓRNEJ BA3-1','300-020-001 - BOK POKRYWY GÓRNEJ')
INSERT INTO PodZlozenie (NumerPodZlozenia, NumerCzesci) VALUES ('300-021-001 - ZŁOŻENIE POKRYWY GÓRNEJ BA3-1','300-020-002 - DEKIEL POKRYWY GÓRNEJ')
INSERT INTO PodZlozenie (NumerPodZlozenia, NumerCzesci) VALUES ('300-021-001 - ZŁOŻENIE POKRYWY GÓRNEJ BA3-1','300-020-003 - KĄTOWNIK')
INSERT INTO PodZlozenie (NumerPodZlozenia, NumerCzesci) VALUES ('300-021-001 - ZŁOŻENIE POKRYWY GÓRNEJ BA3-1','300-020-004 - WSTAWKA UZUPEŁNIAJĄCA')
INSERT INTO PodZlozenie (NumerPodZlozenia, NumerCzesci) VALUES ('300-021-002 - ZŁOŻENIE POKRYWY DOLNEJ TYŁ BA3-1','300-020-010 - BLASZKA PROWADZĄCA POKRYWĘ')
INSERT INTO PodZlozenie (NumerPodZlozenia, NumerCzesci) VALUES ('300-021-002 - ZŁOŻENIE POKRYWY DOLNEJ TYŁ BA3-1','300-020-011 - POKRYWA DOLNA TYŁ BA3-1')
INSERT INTO PodZlozenie (NumerPodZlozenia, NumerCzesci) VALUES ('300-021-002 - ZŁOŻENIE POKRYWY DOLNEJ TYŁ BA3-1','300-020-012 - PŁASKOWNIK BA3-1')
INSERT INTO PodZlozenie (NumerPodZlozenia, NumerCzesci) VALUES ('300-021-003 - ZŁOŻENIE POKRYWY DOLNEJ PRZÓD BA3-1','300-020-013 - WZMOCNIENIE POKRYWY')
INSERT INTO PodZlozenie (NumerPodZlozenia, NumerCzesci) VALUES ('300-021-003 - ZŁOŻENIE POKRYWY DOLNEJ PRZÓD BA3-1','300-020-014 - UCHWYT')
INSERT INTO PodZlozenie (NumerPodZlozenia, NumerCzesci) VALUES ('300-021-003 - ZŁOŻENIE POKRYWY DOLNEJ PRZÓD BA3-1','300-020-015 - POKRYWA DOLNA PRZÓD BA3-1')
```

**#EDIT
Querry should return desired output as follow:**

```
IF Zlozenie.NumerCzesci CONTAINS "ZŁOŻENIE" THEN SELECT PodZlozenie.NumerCzesci FROM PodZlozenie WHERE Zlozenie.NumerCzesci = PodZlozenie.NumerPodZlozenia ELSE Zlozenie.NumerCzesci
```

Desired output:

```
[NumerCzesci]
300-000-001 - WKŁADKA GÓRNA
300-000-002 - WKŁADKA DOLNA
300-000-003 - UCHO ROTORA 11 RAM 3 SEKCJE
300-000-005 - RAMIĘ ROTORA 565mm
300-020-001 - BOK POKRYWY GÓRNEJ
300-020-002 - DEKIEL POKRYWY GÓRNEJ
300-020-003 - KĄTOWNIK
300-020-004 - WSTAWKA UZUPEŁNIAJĄCA
300-020-010 - BLASZKA PROWADZĄCA POKRYWĘ
300-020-011 - POKRYWA DOLNA TYŁ BA3-1
300-020-012 - PŁASKOWNIK BA3-1
300-020-013 - WZMOCNIENIE POKRYWY
300-020-014 - UCHWYT
300-020-015 - POKRYWA DOLNA PRZÓD BA3-1
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum! Could you please provide a fiddle with data the works - see [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=f859a8e528f5e870ab6755818bf8b01f) - there are no matches on the JOIN... please correct as applicable!

Comment: Hello Verace, thats probably also a problem with my querry.. I dont know how to write this querry to return desired output based on data that i have provided

Comment: Is this something to do with replacing parts with other similar parts?

Comment: Its like replacing part if contains "ZLOŻENIE" with other parts from second table.. I edit and explain exacly what im trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand your examples correctly it looks like you want the unique list of `NumerCzesci` values from both tables, except when `Zlozenie.NumerCzesci` contains "ZŁOŻENIE". Then you want to use `PodZlozenie.NumerCzesci` instead. You should be able to achieve that with a `FULL JOIN` and a `DISTINCT` clause like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CASE 
        WHEN Zlozenie.NumerCzesci LIKE '%ZŁOŻENIE%' OR Zlozenie.NumerCzesci IS NULL THEN PodZlozenie.NumerCzesci 
        ELSE Zlozenie.NumerCzesci 
    END AS NumerCzesci
FROM Zlozenie
FULL JOIN PodZlozenie
    ON Zlozenie.NumerCzesci = PodZlozenie.NumerPodZlozenia
```

(You can optionally add `ORDER BY NumerCzesci` to the end of the above query if you want the results sorted by `NumerCzesci` in ascending order.)

Comment: Thank You J.D for answer. Your querry returns for example "300-021-001 - ZŁOŻENIE POKRYWY GÓRNEJ BA3-1" in this place it should return all PodZlozenie.NumerCzesci from PodZlozenie where PodZlozenie.NumerPodZlozenia = "300-021-001 - ZŁOŻENIE POKRYWY GÓRNEJ BA3-1"

Comment: @KubaDo Sorry I had a typo in the `LIKE` operator of my query missing the `%` sign. I just fixed it, please try again.

Comment: Thank You very much !

Comment: @KubaDo Much welcome!